# Mongodb unique value

Tags: mongodb

I am a complete beginner in mongodb. I want to do the mongodb equivalence of sql `select distinct column`. i.e. For a mongodb collection with the following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxcbf"),
    "date" : "1462514997209",
    "user_ids" : [ 
        "userXXXX"
    ],  
    "created" : 1462543716,
    "processed" : 1462543716
}
```

How to find unique `user_ids` in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) like (assuming your collection name is `collection1`)

```
db.collection1.distinct( "user_ids" )
```